# Java deleting folder and sub-folder 4th level

Tags: java, file-io, delete-directory

I want delete folder (directory) and sub-directory in JAVA, I need 2 conditions when there's file and where the folder is empty. I've been searched and trying all example I found, but not worked. Even when that code works, that just delete the file or just 1 folder (directory level 4) not all folder.

I want to delete old directory year\place\owner\month\file.

```
File source = new File("C:\\Users\\Workspaces\\projects\\uploadFolder\\year\\place\\owner\\month\\file");
Path sources = source.toPath();
```

I've tried this:

```
 public static void rmdir(final File folder) {
      if (folder.isDirectory())   {
          File[] list = folder.listFiles();
          if (list != null){
              for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                  File tmpF = list[i];
                  if (tmpF.isDirectory()) {
                  rmdir(tmpF); }

                  tmpF.delete();}
          }

          if (!folder.delete()){
            System.out.println("can't delete folder : " + folder);}}
  }
```

This:

```
public static void deleteDirectory(File path) 
{
    if (path == null)
        return;
    if (path.exists())
    {
        for(File f : path.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.isDirectory()) 
            {
                deleteDirectory(f);
                f.delete();
            }
            else
            {
                f.delete();
            }
        }
        path.delete();
    }
}
```

This :

```
public static void deleteFiles (File file)
{    
    if(file.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();   //All files and sub folders
        for(int x=0; files != null && x<files.length; x++)
            deleteFiles(files[x]);   
        file.delete();
    }

}
```

This:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(source);
```

This:

```
Files.delete(sources);
```

Comment: `not worked`, you means `exception` or what?

Comment: There's no exception, but just delete one folder. @Càphêđen

Comment: The first 2 code snippets used `File#delete()`, which only returns `true/false`  for `success/false` result. Thus there is no exception. Please check the results of those lines. `FileUtils#deleteDirectory(source);` is just the wrapper for `File#delete()`, which checks for `symlink`. `Files#delete()` will throw exception if not successful.

Comment: @Càphêđen when I used Files.delete() the exception : [http-nio-8080-exec-4] for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path []

Comment: please provide the full stack trace to find the root cause. Or you can try debugging the 2 first options to find which files break the process.